# eclipse android - adding references does not work anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, reference

When I'm adding a reference through the reference dialog, it adds the reference and adds a green check mark next to it. After closing the dialog then reopening it, there's a red cross next to the reference instead of a green check mark and I can no longer use this reference.

The weird thing is, all other projects work correctly. I can reference projects with no problem, but in this project, I can only reference one other project, the others don't work.

**Question**:

Can anyone point me to something that could create such a behaviour?

Comment: check two project are same path(reference project and your project)

Comment: thx a lot, THAT was it... I mapped my drive to another one and mixed them up when importing the projects...